# single quotes are getting converted into the backstik in sql query: wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

> $login_sql="SELECT * FROM tbuser_info WHERE user_name='".$user."' AND
>   password='".$pass."' AND is_approve='".$approve."'";

is my php variable defining a sql query...
But when it getting executed in wordpress the single quotes are converting into backstik...

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
$login_sql = "SELECT * ROM tbuser_info WHERE user_name=\"{$user}\" AND password=\"{$pass}\" AND is_approve=\"{$approve}\"";
```

Comment: SELECT * ROM tbuser_info WHERE user_name=\’my user\’ AND password=\’password\’ AND is_approve=\’true\’

is output am getting... in worpress
@HerrSerker

Comment: It seems, you have a rewrite process afterwards. Do you have any unusual modules?

Comment: cause am new to wordpress :(

Answer (score 0):

You've posted the query itself but not the code that actually queries the database. I suspect your problem is in that code. However, I recommend this:

```
$login_sql="SELECT * FROM tbuser_info WHERE user_name=%s AND password=%s AND is_approve=%s";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($login_sql,$user,$pass,$approve));
```

That should solve your quotes problem, as `$wpdb->prepare` will add them for strings. It also helps solve SQL injections issues.

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb